# Ajax appended objects not visible in the dom

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

Hi I have a coffeescript like this:

```
$(document).on 'change', '#add_skill_form', ->
  skill_name = $('#character_skill_of_objects option:selected').text()
  if $('#skill_' + skill_name).length == 0 
    $.ajax
      url: 'on_add_skill'
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        skill_id: $('#character_skill_of_objects option:selected').val()
      }
  else 
    alert 'Skill already in use'
```

Inside my view I have some static skills generated, and for them this validation works nice. But when new object is added dynamicly, the validation doesn`t work for him.

This is my add function, where `#skill_list` is an`ul`, and add_skill partial adds `li` objects to it:

```
'<%= form_for [current_user, @character] do |f| %>'
  $('#skill_list').append("<%= j render partial: 'add_skill', locals: { character: @character, skill: @skill, f: f } %> ");
'<% end %>'
```

I assume that the `DOM` is not reloaded after new object is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a scope problem. Since new objects are dynamically added, you have to be careful with your binding scope.

The bind actions will "listen" to what you've bound (in this case, the "change").

BUT since you're trying to find the element by itself (i.e: `$(element)`), the JS will try to find it in the "static DOM" (I mean, it won't care about the DOM modifications that happened after the page first loaded).

So, using a scope, the JS will "listen" to any change inside this scope, and then it'll be able to "listen" to the dynamic modification (i.e: `$(some_main_div).find(element)`).

Comment: the add_skill_form is a drop down select menu, and new elements are added to the skill_list ul, as a li

Comment: try to get the skill using a scope, smth like `if $(document).find('#skill_' + skill_name)`

Comment: It worked !! :) Can you please give more explanation in the answer ?

Comment: I've updated my answer! You can get more information here http://api.jquery.com/on/ :)